# No file sourced in non-login shells

Tags: linux, xorg, xterm, busybox

In login shells, no problem : `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are sourced. But in non-login shells (xterm in XOrg), they aren't. The `$HOME` variable isn't even set.

I'm using [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/) and the Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`). The only user is root, with autologin.

How to tell if in login or non-login shell : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237672

How can I fix it ?

Platform : x86, Buildroot, Busybox, Xorg, Fluxbox, Busybox init

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it. I was calling startx from a `/etc/init.d/rcS` script, so of course, there was no previous login environment to propagate. Now, I call startx from `/etc/profile.d/startx.sh`, only if X is not running.